# Can I change the position of navigationbar item?

Tags: iphone, ios

Here is the snapshot:
[image]

And the code is here:

```
UIButton *leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
leftButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 46.0f, 32.0f);
[leftButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navi_register_up.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doRegister) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *leftBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarItem;
[leftBarItem release];
```

Is there any way to move the button up some px?
Thank you:)

Answer (score 72):

You need to create a `UIBarButtonItem` with system item `UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace` with -5 width which will remove `5 px` padding. Then set `leftBarButtonItems` with both fixed space item and your back bar item like this -

```
UIBarButtonItem *negativeSpacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
[negativeSpacer setWidth:-5];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:negativeSpacer,leftBarItem,nil];
```

Comment: Works great if you need to move UIBarButtonItem horizontally.

Comment: Hmm, this works, but only seems to work for one button.  using a second spacer and button doesn't seem to work. thoughts?

Comment: smart and clean. fantastic solution :)

Comment: I tried several different approaches and this is the only one that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: What if we want to move item vertically?

Comment: @Umitk in that case using a view and placing two buttons vertically and then using UIBarButtonItem with custom view is a good option.

Answer (score 16):

You can try this,

```
leftButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-2, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: @理想评论学派, I have tested this, it can move the UIButton's image up.:)

Comment: Do you test with my code? Just add "leftButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-2, 0, 0, 0);" ? I will check it again

Comment: i have text and background color. when i set edgeInsets, it moves the text, not the button frame...:(

Comment: Almost working. The image stretches out vertically unless you also specify a positive bottom inset: UIEdgeInsetsMake(-2, 0, 2, 0). At least that's my case (iOS 8).

Answer (score 4):

Add a `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace` item in between the items you want to separate.

Comment: UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace can separate items in horizontal. But I want to move the button up. Can UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace help?

Comment: Not vertically, no. You can always utilize a UIToolbar and add a UILabel with the frame you need to position it vertically then add the appropriate buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Swift 3 version of the most voted answer:

```
 let soundButton = UIBarButtonItem(image:image , style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.soundPressed))

        let negativeSpacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        negativeSpacer.width = -5

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [negativeSpacer,soundButton]
```

Answer (score 0):

The height of a standard bar button is 29pt. Do yourself a favor and just shrink `leftbutton`'s height and `navi_register_up.png`'s height instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code,I think this will be helpful to you.
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,50,32);
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(BackBtnClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIView *backButtonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 32)];
backButtonView.bounds = CGRectOffset(backButtonView.bounds, -1, -4);
[backButtonView addSubview:button];

UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButtonView];
//barButtonItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-6, 20, 30, 0);

[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and found an option that sufficed in the storyboard. Just click on the navbar item and you should see the x/y position options.

[image]