# Change the start y axies of rightBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem

I've the following Custom Button on rightBarButtonItem

```
UIButton *button1 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
button1.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,105,30);
[button1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"image1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button1 addTarget:appDelegate action:@selector(Open_Link1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:button1];
[button1 release];
```

I need to move the rightBarButtonItem up 2 px  ...

I've tried set it but doesn't work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`button1.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-4, 0, 0, 0);`

The answer here: [Can I change the position of navigationbar item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866062/can-i-change-the-position-of-navigationbar-item)

*Beware, you change insets of the button that to be assigned to the rightBarButtonItem, not the rightBarButtonItem itself.*

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this `button1.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,105,30);` to `button1.frame=CGRectMake(0,-2,105,30);`

Comment: then i fear you have to change the image iteslf

Comment: I've seen this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866062/can-i-change-the-position-of-navigationbar-item but cannot get anything out ... can you help here?

Comment: his problem was different, he wanted x displacement not y